# Overwrite an excel sheet with pandas dataframe without affecting other sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I want to overwrite an existing sheet in an excel file with Pandas dataframe but don't want any changes in other sheets of the same file. How this can be achieved.
I tried below code but instead of overwriting, it is appending the data in 'Sheet2'.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet2', index = False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I didn't find any other option other than this, this would be a quick solution for you.

I believe still there's no direct way to do this, correct me if I'm wrong. That's the reason we need to play with these logical ways.

```
import pandas as pd

def write_excel(filename,sheetname,dataframe):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
        workBook = writer.book
        try:
            workBook.remove(workBook[sheetname])
        except:
            print("Worksheet does not exist")
        finally:
            dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname,index=False)
            writer.save()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2':['foo','bar','foobar','barfoo','foofoo','barbar']})

write_excel('PRODUCT.xlsx','PRODUCTS',df)
```

Let me know if you found this helpful, or ignore it if you need any other better solution.

Comment: I tried this but it deleted all other sheets in the file

Comment: No, Certainly not. I tried. Did you pass the correct sheet name?

Comment: Works perfectly fine .... An update just remove `writer.save()` from the function as it's not part of the public API

Answer (score 11):

Similar to Gavaert's answer... For Pandas 1.3.5, add the 'if_sheet_exists="replace"' option:

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Logs', index=False)
```

Comment: I get this error io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate

Comment: and it creates the copy of Logs1

Answer (score 1):

Since Pandas version 1.3.0 `on_sheet_exists` is an option of `ExcelWriter`. It can be used as such:

```py
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter("my_sheet.xlsx",engine="openpyxl",mode="a",on_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    pd.write_excel(writer,df)
```

Since none of the `ExcelWriter` methods or properties are public, it is advised to not use them.

Comment: if_sheet_exists is the correct parameter

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I faced the same issue recently and answers are not worked for me and here is how I solved the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

filename = 'path\to\the\file.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(filename)
wb.activate()
wb.app.screen_updating = False #xl will open and freeze
wb.app.display_alerts = False
wb.app.calculation = 'manual'

ws = wb.sheets['Sheet Name To Change']
ws.value = <DataFrameName>


wb.activate()
wb.app.screen_updating = True
wb.app.display_alerts = True
wb.app.calculation = 'automatic'
wb.save()
```

Let me know if you found this helpful, I am not very familiar with answering so please correct any kind of error.